# Add Priority in Favorite Tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

I was thinking that it could be useful to have a priority in favorite tags.

In its personal profile page each user could specify exactly as happens in the question page of SO a list of Favorite Tags and assign each one a priority.

[image]

In this way visualization of questions could change (maybe just colors, or have a some kind of evidence given in the question list) on the basis of priority of a question to each particular user.

Comment: Why didn't you just include the suggestion in this question? Then we could have edited out the part of you asking if it belonged here and just kept the suggestion.

Comment: adding it just now

Comment: @animuson added...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow custom colorization of tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78849/allow-custom-colorization-of-tags)