# Favorite tag improvements

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow custom colorization of tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78849/allow-custom-colorization-of-tags)

**A: [Allow custom colorization of tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78849/allow-custom-colorization-of-tags)**

Sorry it was an duplicate :(

**B: Quick deactivate/activate tags**

If you click a tag in the favorite-tags section it will temporarily unfavorized until you click it again (it stays in the list.)

**C: Create custom tag collections**

Let the user create it's own combinations of tags which should only be preferred if they are mentioned together like "Javascript + jQuery" or in other case are only ignored when mentioned together like "C+threading" (when you don't know enough about threading in C e.g. but still wan to see questions with C or (Java+Threading) )